# Lua string.gmatch pattern for multiple commas in a row

Tags: regex, lua, openresty

The URI contains values that are separated by three consecutive commas.

e.g.  /path?first,,,second,,,third,value,,,fourth

I would like to iterate the values and print the word like:

```
first
second
third,value
fourth
```

This example only finds one comma and the third value fails as it contains a single comma.

```
for word in string.gmatch(ngx.var.request_uri, "[^,]+") do ngx.say(word) end
```

This also does not work:

```
for word in string.gmatch(ngx.var.request_uri, "[^,]{3}") do ngx.say(word) end
```

What is the proper regex pattern to only use three consecutive commas in a row in this example?

Comment: This patter should do what you need:`",,,([^,]+)" `

Comment: The first value is lost when using that pattern @Nifim

Comment: You might not be able to capture first and forth with a single pattern. one requires it be followed by 3 `,` the other requires them to be lead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this will work as you need:

```
local function process_param(s)
    print(s)
end

local path = "/path?first,,,second,,,third,value,,,fourth"
local first = string.match(path, "?([^,]+[,]?[^,]+)")
process_param(first)

for word in string.gmatch(path, ",,,([^,]+[,]?[^,]+)") do
    process_param(word)
end
```

This example requires a separate step to get the `first` value as it does not have a leading `,,,`. I am capturing the desired part of the string by using `(`, this allows you to specify the surrounding chars without including them in the output. I used `[,]?` to allow for a single comma to appear withing the captured string allowing the result to return `third,value`

This produces:

```
first
second
third,value
fourth
```

Resource: [understanding_lua_patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)

Comment: local first = string.match(path, "?([^,]+)") << this line fails if the first string value contains a single comma.  e.g. /path?first,value,,,second...

Answer (score 0):

You may remove all up to `?`, then replace the `,,,` with a char that is not likely to appear in the string (say, `\0`, as [suggested by Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991710/lua-string-gmatch-pattern-for-multiple-commas-in-a-row/54991804?noredirect=1#comment96752391_54991804)), and then use `"[^\0]+"` pattern to extract the items you need.

See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/9TRKy4):

```
local s = "/path?first,,,second,,,third,value,,,fourth"
s = s:gsub("^[^?]*%?", ""):gsub(",,,", "\0")
for word in string.gmatch(s, "[^\0]+") do print(word) end
```

Output:

```
first
second
third,value
fourth
```

So, with `gsub("^[^?]*%?", "")`, all text from the start of the string till the first `?` together with `?` is removed, then `gsub(",,,", "\0")` replaces `,,,` with a zero-byte char, and the `string.gmatch(s, "[^\0]+")` does the multiple matching as expected.

**LuaJIT version**

The `[^\0]` is not valid in LuaJIT, hence the `gmatch`ing should be performed using `%Z+` pattern that matches 1 or more chars other than zero-byte char (the `%z` is the character with representation `0` as per the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)).

See the test snippet:

```
> s = "/path?first,,,second,,,third,value,,,fourth"
> s = s:gsub("^[^?]*%?", ""):gsub(",,,", "\0")
> for word in string.gmatch(s, "%Z+") do print(word) end
first
second
third,value
fourth
```

Comment: I like this example.  However, the character replacement will not work.  One of the string in the URL is an escaped user agent string in which any character can appear including a single |

Comment: @Kevin I doubt the chars from the [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) is that likely to appear there.

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, using `utf8.char(57344)` is a bad idea.  It would be better to use "\0" instead.  Zero byte is guaranteed to not present in user string. `for word in s:gsub(",,,", "\0"):gmatch("%Z+") do print(word) end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you for your input, I edited the solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The question is about openresty which is working usually with LuaJIT, but your pattern `[^\0]` is invalid in LuaJIT .

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am looking way to split string double pipe separated || to split .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027692/regex-split-string-by-two-consecutive-pipe