# Regex split string by two consecutive pipe ||

Tags: regex, lua

I want to split below string by two pipe(|| ) regex .

Input String

```
value1=data1||value2=da|ta2||value3=test&user01|
```

Expected Output

```
value1=data1
value2=da|ta2
value3=test&user01|
```

I tried `([^||]+)` but its consider single pipe | also to split .

Try out my example - [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/TVimAr/1)

value2 has single pipe it should not be considered as matching.

I am using lua script like

```
for pair in string.gmatch(params, "([^||]+)") do 
 print(pair) 
end
```

Comment: This almost works: `for w in string.gmatch(s.." ||","(.-)||") do print(w) end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly find each `||`.

```lua
$ cat foo.lua
s = 'value1=data1||value2=da|ta2||value3=test&user01|'

offset = 1
for idx in string.gmatch(s, '()||') do
    print(string.sub(s, offset, idx - 1) )
    offset = idx + 2
end
-- Deal with the part after the right-most `||`.
-- Must +1 or it'll fail to handle s like "a=b||".
if offset <= #s + 1 then
    print(string.sub(s, offset) )
end
$ lua foo.lua
value1=data1
value2=da|ta2
value3=test&user01|
```

---

Regarding `()||` see Lua's doc about [Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) <sup>(Lua does not have regex support)</sup> —

> - **Captures:**
>
>   A pattern can contain sub-patterns **enclosed in parentheses**; they describe captures. When a match succeeds, the substrings of the subject string that match captures are stored (captured) for future use. Captures are numbered according to their left parentheses. For instance, in the pattern `"(a*(.)%w(%s*))"`, the part of the string matching `"a*(.)%w(%s*)"` is stored as the first capture, and therefore has number 1; the character matching `"."` is captured with number 2, and the part matching `"%s*"` has number 3.
>
>   As a **special case**, the capture `()` captures the current string position (a number). For instance, if we apply the pattern `"()aa()"` on the string `"flaaap"`, there will be two captures: 3 and 5.

Comment: Great ! What does ()|| mean? Could you please explain the regex?

Comment: @SumeetKumarYadav `()` is a special capture which captures the current position - in this case the index of the first pipe. By subtracting `1`, this is excluded.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to replace the sequence of 2 characters `||` with any other character (e.g. `;`) that will not be used in the data, and only then use it as a separator:

```
local params = "value1=data1||value2=da|ta2||value3=test&user01|"

for pair in string.gmatch(params:gsub('||',';'), "([^;]+)") do 
 print(pair) 
end
```

if all characters are possible, then any non-printable characters can be used, according to their codes: `string.char("10") == "\10" == "\n"`
even with code 1: `"\1"`

```
string.gmatch( params:gsub('||','\1'), "([^\1]+)" )
```

Comment: We have a constraint that any other single character could appear in string , like ; could appear . Could it be done without replacing

Comment: you can use any non-printable characters `LF=> string.char('10')  == "\10" == \n` or any other, even with code 1 : `\1`

Comment: Thanks , How do we know the list of non-printable characters in LUA ?

Comment: use any character from [ascii table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: local params = "value1=da\1ta1||value2=da|ta2||value3=test&user01|"


for pair in string.gmatch( params:gsub('||','\1'), "([^\1]+)" ) do 
 print(pair) 
end
Output value1=da
ta1
value2=da|ta2
value3=test&user01|

Comment: If string has \1 it breaks as it will consider \1 to split

Comment: String can contain non printable charcter like \10 , \1 . Example value1=da\1ta1||value2=da|ta2||value3=test&user01|

Comment: no, \1 - is a non-printable char with code 01, but char "1" has the code 49

Comment: really any chars? even da\1ta ?  this is a symbol from the printer 's control sequence , it doesn 't make sense to use it in other places... just pick a possible symbol from the table https://www.ascii-code.com

Comment: This may be simple, but since it may collide with another character, I would consider this a dirty hack.